# What is the ideal collection type for an adjecency list of a Graph implemented in .NET?

Tags: .net, algorithm, collections, f#

According to Sedgewick's algorithm book he uses a *Bag* collection from Java to implement adjacency lists of Graphs. And it makes perfect sense since for searching in O(1) and allowing duplicate edges from a Vertex to another. 
List can be used but they are slow in search as in O(n), so I would avoid it.

Unfortunately .NET doesn't have it. There are implementations like Wintellect but they are not Portable (or .NET standard compatible).
What should I use instead  ?

Comment: Would `Dictionary<T, List<T>>` suffice?

Comment: @Enigmativity, can you elaborate ? Is it like I put the first instance of Vertex to Dictionary as a key as well as add that one and next ones to the List ?

Comment: If you have a set of vertices (of type `T`) that make up the graph, then the key is one vertex and the `List<T>` are all of the vertices that the key vertex connects to. The `Dictionary<T, List<T>>` is then a directed cyclic graph.

Comment: Nope, that wouldn't be efficient. You have just used List<T> as the adjacency list. In your case searching if two vertex are neighbors would take O(n) time  where n is number of neighbors. With a Bag you can answer the same question better as constant time.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't be efficient. I never said it is the most efficient, but it works. If you want efficient then `Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>` would be better.

Comment: That also wouldn't work. You won't be able to add multiple edges between vertexes :)  We need a Bag. But a bag can be implemented as a Dictionary<T,List<T>> I suppose. Of course then the Graph will have a Dictionary<T,Dictionary<T,List<T>>>

Comment: I don't know in this case if there is a structure that can make all operations O(1). But I think you should state explicitly which operations you want to be O(1) to make easier to answer your question. (i.e. add edge, remove edge, check nodes adjacency, count edges between two adjacent nodes, etc.. whatever matters for your case).

Comment: I think a `Dictionary<T,Dictionary<T,int>>` should be sufficient, where inner dictionary maps nodes to edge counts.

Answer (score 2):

Well after some thinking I implemented my own Bag as a Dictionary<'T,int> 
This is like a multiset or a bag. Here's my implementation in F#:

```
type Bag<'T when 'T : equality>() =
    let dict = Dictionary<'T,int>()
    let mutable count = 0

    member x.Add = (x:>ICollection<'T>).Add

    member x.Remove = (x:>ICollection<'T>).Remove

    member x.Count = (x:>ICollection<'T>).Count

    member x.Clear = (x:>ICollection<'T>).Clear

    member x.ItemCount item =
        match dict.TryGetValue item with
            | true, itemCount -> itemCount
            | _ -> 0

    interface ICollection<'T> with

        member x.Add item =
            count <- count + 1
            let itemCount =
                match dict.TryGetValue item with
               | true, itemCount -> itemCount
               | _ -> 0
            dict.[item] <- itemCount + 1

        member x.Clear() = dict.Clear()

        member x.Contains item = dict.ContainsKey item

        member x.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex) =
            x
            |> Seq.take(array.Length - arrayIndex)
            |> Seq.iteri (fun i item ->  array.[i + arrayIndex] <- item)

        member x.Count = count

        member x.GetEnumerator()  =
            (x :> ICollection<'T>).GetEnumerator() :> Collections.IEnumerator

        member x.GetEnumerator() =
            let seq =
                let innerSeq (kvp : KeyValuePair<'T,int>) =
                     Seq.init kvp.Value (fun _ -> kvp.Key)
                dict |> Seq.map innerSeq |> Seq.collect id
            seq.GetEnumerator()

        member x.IsReadOnly = false

        member x.Remove item =
            match dict.TryGetValue item with
            | true, 1 ->
                count <- count - 1
                dict.Remove item
            | true, itemCount ->
                count <- count - 1 
                dict.[item] <- itemCount - 1
                true
            | _ -> false
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using a `List<T>` instead of just an `int` as the dictionary's values - all you need to maintain is the count, you don't need to add multiple copies of the item.